# Clarification regarding Static local variables

Tags: c++, static

In a link [Storage Class Specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

under the topic **Static local variables**
I read that

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero- or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is first entered).

I don't understand what does it actually mean by saying:

> *which can be performed **before** the block is first entered*

Plus, Does a **static** local variable can be said to be having **No Linkage**?

Could you please throw some examples if necessary? Thanks

Comment: `static int foo=4;` would be one example. But not `static int foo=bar();`. A little understanding of how executable code is loaded by the operating system would be useful here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Any link for that

Comment: Is your Google broken? First hit for "constant initialization c++".

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Let me try and rephrase it. Normally initialisation is performed as the block is first entered, but it certain cases (zero- or constant-initialisation) it can be performed at some earlier time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part is when the init value is known.
When it is known with the additional guarantee that it will not change before the block is first executed.

Below is code with some examples.

```
int foo(void);

void bar(void)
{
    static int ZeroInit;     // zero init
    static int a = 0;        // constant init
    static int b = 4;        // constant init
    // values for above inits are known at start of runtime and even earlier

    static int c = foo();
    // dynamic init, value unknown before execution of foo(),
    // which cannot (i.e. is defined not to) be done before executing the block

    /* code */
}
```